# How to manage a multiple copies of a git project

Tags: git, github

I have made an School Android project and I wanted to make copies of it for different schools with different packages and different drawables. Is there any way to manage all of them in same github repository in different branches. So when I make some changes in one instance(branch) and create pull request for rest of the instances(branches). I want it to merge only the changes I made than replacing all of the code and drawables of the branch from which I created pull request.

Comment: Are you going to be making PRs from the different instance branches towards one common branch (let's say `master` or `develop`) or are you going to make PRs towards the different instance branches?

Comment: I want to make a different branchs or repos (whatever is possible) for every school. But also I want to maintain one code base for upcoming features. I don't want to copy and paste same code for every school. As I tried with different branches for different schools. The problem is, If I update code in master branch and create pull requests for other branches, that pull request also replaces packages and drawables with master. Which I definitely don't want. I'm looking for a better management way.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is to extract the core part of your project into a separate, manageable repository. Let's call it your `coreApp`. It will contain the main functionalities, features and architecture that is needed for all of the subsequent work you'll be doing. **Given that it is even possible to separate your project into modules!**

Then for each specific project (the copies for the different schools) will use your `coreApp` as a dependency and will build on top of it, implementing the concrete and specific drawablase + packages it needs.

The **Pros** of this approach is that you have a clear logical separation between each project. The git history will be specific, detailed and exact. You'll know when you need to update your core module and when you need to work on each specific project. You also gain the benefit of handling smaller pojects that way. Since each project is just a different application, you are moving away from creating a monolith, to a more modulized system. Another positive is that you have a small amount of code duplication. All you need to do is just implement specific and concrete features for each school, the rest stays the same.

The **Cons** are that it will be harder to manage all of these projects, due to the fact that now you don't have *one* single project, but multiple ones, where one is a dependency on the other. The other negative aspect of that is that if it happens, and this is very dependent on your situation, if you regularly update your `coreApp`, then you might *need* to update all subsequent project, since your core got a new version. This depends on how active you are with your maintenance. And last, *but not least* negative is that, it might be quite difficult to logically separate your core from the rest of your apps...

Also I personally would try to move away from having everything managed in a single git repo, especially if features will be constantly overwritten for other purposes, because things will get out of hand quickly. You might loose the logical consistency of your project development and managing the history *might* become difficult.